# ASP.NET Html helper displays one vaue but not the other from an if statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, conditional-statements, html-helper, forms

I'm trying to display a field for entered by in a form.  The filed should be populated by the username, but with the option to change the data.  If the field has been set to a custom value then it shouldn’t be overwritten by the username on edit.
The issue I am having is that using Html helpers the value attribute of the input is never set to the username.  I can't see any reason why the value would not be set if anyone can see what I am missing or any ideas.
The code I wanted to use is as follows. however, using this code if EnteredBy is not set then the value of the input is set to null.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteredBy, new { @class = "form-control", value = (Model.EnteredBy == null) ? (fullName ?? username) : Model.EnteredBy })
```

To check that the conditional statement is correct I tried the following, I added a break point and the enteredBy variable is getting set to the correct value i.e. the username if Model.EnteredBy is null.  However, the value attribute of the input is still set to null if Model.EnterdBy is null.  Even though the enteredBy variable has the correct value and if Model.EnterdBy has a value the value atribute is set correctly.

```
                string enteredBy = (Model.EnteredBy == null) ? (fullName ?? username) : Model.EnteredBy;
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteredBy, new { @class = "form-control", value = enteredBy })
```

To resolve the issue I used the following code not using Html helpers which works fine.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="@((Model.EnteredBy == null) ? (fullName ?? username) : Model.EnteredBy)" />
```

I just really cannot work out why the html helper did not work.  If anyone can see what I'm missing it would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods. Set the value of the property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

Comment: Try using `@Value = (Model.EnteredBy == null) ? (fullName ?? username) : Model.EnteredBy`

Comment: @Phiter That works fine thanks.  I am still confused why my way worked when the condition was false but not true though.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why should I not set the value in the View, is it just good practice?

Comment: Because the whole point of using the `HtmlHelper` methods is to get correct 2-way model binding (plus validation etc). By setting the `value` attribute your losing the correct functionality (and it will not work correctly if `ModelState` is invalid and you return the view.

Comment: Besides, code like that belongs in the controller, not the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your comments.  I only graduated this year so still a lot to learn.  I knew logic needed to go into the controller but I thought the occasional condition statements was ok in the View.  I have refactored my code now and set the value in the controller.